# Using BigInteger, how can I pass the sign of my binary number to get it as an int?

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

I'm trying to convert binary strings to signed decimal numbers. I am trying to figure out a way to do that with 10 bit binary strings.

```
String i = kb.next();
int p = new BigInteger(i, 2).intValue();
```

The above code will convert a binary string to a decimal number however you need to enter the sign and a 32-bit string. Is there anyway I could pass a 10-bit string and it return the correct decimal number.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the API that explicitly says that you need to have all 32 bits represented in the string; but if you're sure that's what you need, simply append a string with 0s to the front of `i`.

Comment: Since you're calling `intValue`, couldn't you use `Integer.valueOf(i, 2).intValue()`?

Comment: Give an example of input and wanted output.

Comment: So let's say I have a 10 bit string 1(0000001011).. This would be -11.. But if I enter that string now, it will interpret that as an incomplete positive binary string.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the code you gave and it's still works. If you still want to pass a 32-bit String, however, you could use this code:

```
while(i.length()<32){
    i = "0"+i;
}
```

this code fill the given string with 0s before to make a 32-bit integer.